# Testing and mocking a function which does not return any value

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, gomock

I want to test a function, which does not return any value, but instead triggers other functions. While reading about testing, I found information that this is called a behavioral verification and that by mocking I can check what functions and in what order are triggered. However, I have a problem to implement the proper mocking technique for my code.

Let's consider a simple example of the following interface and struct (the example is very basic just to make it easier to explain):

```
type ExampleInterface interface {
    DoSomething(arg int)
    DoEvenMore(arg int)
    AndEvenMore(arg int)
} 

type ExampleStruct struct {
     Id string 
     // Other fields
}

func (e *ExampleStruct) DoSomething(arg int) {
     arg2 := arg * 2
     e.DoEvenMore(arg2)
     arg3 := arg * 3
     e.AndEvenMore(arg3)  
}

func (e *ExampleStruct) DoEvenMore(arg int){
     fmt.Println("I did so many operations here using ", arg)
}

func (e *ExampleStruct) AndEvenMore(arg int) {
     // Performing other operations on arg
}
```

Now, I want to test function `DoSomething`. Since it does not return any value what I want to do is to test whether after calling this function with argument 3 the following chain of events happens: function `DoEvenMore` is called once with argument `6`, and next function `AndEvenMore` is called once with argument `9`

I wrote the following mocking test:

```
func TestDoSomething(t *testing.T) {

    mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer mockCtrl.Finish()

    mockClient := mocks.NewMockExampleInterface(mockCtrl)

    example := ExampleStruct("ExampleId")

    gomock.InOrder(
        mockClient.EXPECT().DoSomething(3).Return().Times(1)
        mockClient.EXPECT().DoEvenMore(6).Return().Times(1)
        mockClient.EXPECT().AndEvenMore(9).Return().Times(1) 
    )

    example.DoSomething(3)
}
```

However, when I run this test I get the error: `Unexpected call to *mocks.MockExampleInterface.DoSomething(..)`.

How I should properly perform the mocking in such example?

Comment: What is the purpose of testing something which doesn't have any effect? None. If the method call has an effect, here a side effect, test for this side effect. This might be state change of the object (simple to observe) or a state change in the environment (harder to test). Mocking is often a sign for a bad test plan and/or bad design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two methods called by `DoSomething` are concrete implementations, you cannot mock something like that in Go.

To achieve what you want `DoSomething` would have to *depend* on an interface that defines those two methods and call those instead of the concrete ones.

```
type DoMorer interface {
    DoEvenMore(arg int)
    AndEvenMore(arg int)
} 

type ExampleStruct struct {
     Id string 
     // Other fields
}

func (e *ExampleStruct) DoSomething(arg int, dm DoMorer) {
     arg2 := arg * 2
     dm.DoEvenMore(arg2)
     arg3 := arg * 3
     dm.AndEvenMore(arg3)  
}
```

With a setup like this, during testing, you can create a mock for the `DoMorer` interface and pass that to `DoSomething`.

---

`DoMorer` doesn't have to be passed to as an argument, it could be a field of `ExampleStruct` or a global, whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks a lot!